# Is there a difference in meaning between "pleased with" and "pleased about"?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-verbs

They say

> I'm pleased with your **work \ performance** (the noun implies duty or
>   effort)
>
> I'm pleased about your **wedding \ promotion** (the noun is about some event)

Is there a difference in meaning between **"pleased with" and "pleased about"**?

Answer (score 2):

"Pleased *with*" normally precedes something that you have an active interest or control in.

"Please *about*" is more appropriate when the subject is not something that you have any active interest or control in.

For example:

> I am pleased with my exam results.

Your exam results are something you personally worked for, so you are rightly pleased with them.

> I am pleased with my son's exam results.

A parent also has an active interest in their child's education, so it wouldn't be surprising for them to say they are pleased *with* them.

> I am pleased about your exam results.

Someone without an active interest may politely express their own pleasure upon hearing the news by saying they are pleased *about* them.

---

With your examples of *performance* and *promotion*, I would say:

> I am pleased *with* your performance.

I would imagine this is the most likely version, as I can't imagine anyone who wasn't actively interested in your performance to comment on it; however "about" could be correct in other contexts.

> I am pleased *about* your promotion.

I would expect this to be most likely, as a promotion is very personal to the individual promoted and not much benefit to anyone else.